# "Previous load of class failed", "Invalid type" for inner interface

Tags: apex, unit-test, ant

I'm experiencing the following error during the test phase of a (check-only) ant deployment:

> line -1, column -1: Previous load of class failed:
>   ComplimentaryTestDomain: line 1, column 75: Invalid type:
>   CaseDomainFactory.ComplimentaryTest

The "Invalid type" (CaseDomainFactory.ComplimentaryTest) is an inner interface of the following class, defined on the last line:

```
public class CaseDomainFactory {
    public static Cases createCaseDomain(List<CaseSubmission> caseSubmissionCollection){ 
        Cases caseCollection;
        String caseType = caseSubmissionCollection[0].caseToSubmit.Type;
        if(caseType == 'Duplicate Super Bills'){
            caseCollection = (Cases)DIContainer.getDependency('CaseDomainFactory.DuplicateSBs');
        } 
        else if(caseType == 'Recoupment' || caseType == 'Audit'){
            caseCollection = (Cases)DIContainer.getDependency('CaseDomainFactory.RecoupmentAudit');
        }
        else if(caseType == 'Incorrect Carrier Selected'){
            caseCollection = (Cases)DIContainer.getDependency('CaseDomainFactory.IncorrectCarrierCase');
        }
        else if(caseType == 'Complimentary Test'){
            caseCollection = (Cases)DIContainer.getDependency('CaseDomainFactory.ComplimentaryTest');
        }
        else {
            caseCollection = (Cases)DIContainer.getDependency('Cases');
        }
        caseCollection.construct(caseSubmissionCollection);
        return caseCollection;
    }

    public interface DuplicateSBs extends Cases{}

    public interface RecoupmentAudit extends Cases{}

    public interface IncorrectCarrierCase extends Cases{}

    public interface ComplimentaryTest extends Cases{}
}
```

The interface is implemented by the following class (from which the error is produced):

```
public class ComplimentaryTestDomain extends CaseDomain implements Cases, CaseDomainFactory.ComplimentaryTest {
   public override List<CaseSubmission> submit(){
        List<CaseSubmission> caseSubmissions = super.submit();
        ComplimentaryTestApproval approvalService = new ComplimentaryTestApproval(caseSubmissions);
        approvalService.processEmployeeTestCases();
        return caseSubmissions;
    }
}
```

The interface itself extends the following interface:

```
public interface Cases {
    void construct(List<CaseSubmission> caseSubmissions);
    List<CaseSubmission> submit();
}
```

Any information about what might be causing this error would be helpful.

Comment: What happens if you compile all classes?

Comment: Are the mentioned interfaces and classes part of the ant deployment?

Comment: Is it because ComplimentaryTestDomain doesn't implement the Cases.submit method?

If not, it could be an issue with some cyclical dependencies. For example, class A depends on class B which depends on class C which references class A. We have experienced ANT deployment issues with complex class structures in the past. Is it possible to make Cases an inner interface as well? Alternatively, you could try to make the inner interfaces top level.

Answer (score 0):

A bad git merge caused the "ApexClass" section of our continuous integration's package.xml to contain a second name tag for a different metadata type. It appears that this caused our new Apex code to not be deployed. Removing the tag resolved the issue.